# How do I set my page so that the Enter key event does not trigger postback?

Tags: jquery, html

In one of my asp web pages there is a textbox, where I use jQuery to display content in textbox above it when user hit the Enter key. However, it always trigger postback, so the content will disappear immediately after displaying. How do I keep that postback from happening?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813095/textbox-causes-button-postback-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$('your selector').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```